# Push notifications-Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, notifications, push-notification, push, statusbar

I am planning to do small project which involves notification's widely but I have no idea where to start from, I need a particular type of notification's which is used in news paper app's.
In this process the app will not be updated but still notify a user of new messages or events and I want to make the message appear in the status bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to learn about Google Cloud Messaging [GCM tutorial](http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/how-to-send-push-notifications-using-gcm-service/)

And you'll have to learn about Android NotificationManager [Notification Manager tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html).  Good luck

Comment: @zulkamain I went through the demo video in GCM tutorial and this exactly what i asked for,thankyou :)

Comment: If that helped you then you can Accept that answer to make it available to other people with the same question

Comment: If you helped him we would have a useful tutorial for GCM. But you were just an arrogant something. Thanks